# Leaflet maxBounds bottom not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

At the moment I make website for a company who wants a custom map on their page. This map is a big a vector map drawn by a graphic designer. So I use leaflet for this but I have an issue. I make it full screen. The issue is I set the bounds and everything and it works on all side except the bottom so when i start moving up and it not goes back to the bottom. The funny thing if I resize the window so for example I make it small and after back to full window size the bottom part works perfectly.

Here is my code so far:

```
var winh = $(window).height();
    var winw = $(window).width();
    var maph = $('#map').height();
    var mapw = $('#map').width();
    var offset = $('#map').offset();
    var centerX = offset.left + mapw / 2;
    var centerY = offset.top + maph / 2;
    var changem = false;
    var cbut = $('#building');
    var southWest = new L.LatLng(winh, 0);
    var northEast = new L.LatLng(0, winw);
    var bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

    var map = L.map('map', {
        maxBounds: bounds,
        maxZoom: 2,
        minZoom: 0,
        crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).setView([winh, winw], 0);
    // .setView([winh, winw], 0)
     map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

    // map.panTo(new L.LatLng(centerY,centerX));

// ----------------------------------
//  Load the images for the map
// ----------------------------------
    var imageUrl =   'http://rigailoveyou.exflairdigital.com/public/img/houses.png'
    var imageUrl2 = 'http://rigailoveyou.exflairdigital.com/public/img/road.png'
    var imageBounds = [[winh,0], [0,winw]];

    var map1 = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, bounds,'Riga I Love You').addTo(map);
    var map2 = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl2, bounds).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Could you perhaps supply a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:QC882oDrJJQk7Li88jj4?p=preview) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Why are you using the window's width and height as latitude and longitude?

Comment: I use them to declare the the max height and width of the map because I want it to work fine on every device. I don't know it makes any sense but I thought it will be good because I use leaflet for the first time and not really figure out how it's work.

Comment: Use the size of the images you're loading, not the current size of the map viewport, as LatLngs for CRS.Simple. Use CSS to make your map fir the device's screen.